# How to Integrate API Module on Definova?

Tags: javascript, python, php, browser-automation

I want to host an app on the definova.club marketplace, but I'm having trouble figuring out the /send API. How can I properly integrate the module so that it takes a commission and checks the user's balance?

I tried following the instructions at https://automationempire.notion.site/API-Reference-EN-d0740d89b9a745fe961b7a749ac17abd

but for some reason it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? Please edit your question to include some code and a description of what happened and how this differs from what you expected to happen. Unfortunately "it didn't work" is too vague to help us to help you.